# Diffeomorphism from $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ to $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 > 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

> Give an example of a diffeomorphism of the class $C^1$ that takes the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ on $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 > 1\}$.

I did this task but I need to make sure it's correct and if it is a sufficient explanation of the problem:

$K=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$
$L=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 > 1\}$

$\Phi: (0,1) \times ( 0, 2\pi] \to K$
$\Phi(r, \alpha) = (r\cos \alpha, r \sin \alpha)$ - diffeomorphism of the class $C^1$
$\Phi \left( (0,1) \times ( 0, 2\pi] \right) =K$
$\Phi^{-1}(K)=(0,1) \times (0, 2\pi]$
$\Phi^{-1}$ is also diffeomorphism of the class $C^1$

$f:(0,1)\times (0,2\pi] \to (1,+\infty) \times (0,2\pi]$
$f(r, \alpha) = (\frac 1r, \alpha)$ - diffeomorphism of the class $C^1$
$f \left( (0,1) \times (0, 2\pi] \right) = (1, +\infty) \times (0, 2\pi]$

$g: (1, +\infty) \times (0, 2\pi] \to L$
$g(r, \alpha) = (r\cos \alpha, r \sin \alpha)$ - diffeomorphism of the class $C^1$
$g \left( (1,+\infty)\times (0, 2\pi] \right) =L$

So $g \circ f \circ \Phi^{-1}$ is searched diffeomorphism of the class $C^1$

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\Phi$ isn't a diffeomorphism, so this is incorrect (it is not even an homeomorphism)

Comment: So how about: in the complex plane, use the map $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$.  It is not only $C^1$, it is holomorphic and conformal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier diffeomorphism takes points $(r_1,\phi_1)$ for $0<r<1$ and $0\le \phi<2\pi$ from domain to points $(r_2,\phi_2)$, where $r_2=1/r_1$ and $\phi_2=\phi_1$. Therefore,
$$
x_2=r_2\cos\phi_2=\frac{\cos\phi_1}{r_1}=\frac{r_1\cos\phi_1}{r_1^2}=\frac{x_1}{x_1^2+y_1^2}.
$$
Similarly, $y_2=\frac{y_1}{x_1^2+y_1^2}$. Hence, the mapping $\Phi(x_1,y_1)=\left(\frac{x_1}{x_1^2+y_1^2},\frac{y_1}{x_1^2+y_1^2}\right)$ defines a diffeomorphism from $\{(x,y):0<x^2+y^2<1\}$ to $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2>1\}$.

**Addendum**

@Ted Shifrin mentioned a good remark that this approach (which is originally inspired from Riemann's sphere mapping to plane) can be extended to any dimensions. For those who are curious, a vectorial mapping between multi-dimensional spaces is
$$
\Phi(\bar x)=\frac{\bar x}{\bar x\cdot\bar x},
$$
where $\cdot$ represents inner product.

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that it will work in any dimension! This is inversion in the unit circle (sphere). Write it vectorially and forget about polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Passing through polar coordinates is the right intuition to have, but the thing is that you function $\Phi$ is not exactly a diffeomorphism: its domain is a rectangle while its codomain is an annulus, and it is clear that these two figures are not even homeomorphic.

Due to the circular symmetry of both $K$ and $L$, one can expect to find a circularly symmetric solution.
In polar coordinates, it would read
$
(r,\theta) \mapsto (f(r), \theta)
$
with $f\colon (0,1)\to (1,+\infty)$ a diffeomorphism.
Let us just translate this intuition into Cartesian coordinates, to make sure everything is well defined.
Recall that we have the relations
\begin{align}
r &= \sqrt{x^2+y^2},
& \cos \theta &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},
& \sin \theta &= \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \\
x &= r\cos \theta, &
\text{and }
y &= r \sin \theta.
\end{align}
The Cartesian coordinates of a point of the form $(f(r),\theta)$ are then $(f(r)\cos\theta, f(r)\sin\theta)$, and it follows that the particular solutions we were looking for would look like
$$
(x,y) \in K \longmapsto \left(f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right),
$$
with $f \colon (0,1) \to (1,+\infty)$ any diffeomorphism.
For instance, $f_0(t)= \frac{1}{t}$, $f_1(t) = 1 - \ln t$ and $f_2(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$ are such functions.

Comment: $f_2$ is not a diffeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$

Comment: @jjagmath Right thanks, edited